# What can I substitute for puff pastry?

Tags: substitutions, low-fat, puff-pastry

I have a recipe that calls for me to roll up turkey in puff pastry. What can I use as a substitute for the puff pastry, preferably that is lower in saturated fat?

Comment: Phyllo, but you'll need to use some butter on it.

Comment: Yeah, phyllo would work, but once you use the butter on it, why not use the puff?

Comment: If you're worried about saturated fat, you could alternatively use phyllo with olive oil instead of butter.

Comment: The term "healthier" has no meaning here. I'll *assume* that you're trying to reduce saturated fat intake and have edited the question accordingly. In the future, please try to be more specific about your nutritional goals when asking a nutrition-related question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Joe,

Whole wheat puff pastry.   It's expensive, and hard to find, though.

Or try another recipe.  If the recipe you're using calls for puff pastry, then the flavor and texture of the puff pastry is going to be a big part of the dish.  It never works very well to substitute a primary ingredient in a recipe.

Comment: My upvote isn't necessarily for the suggestion of whole wheat puff, but for the suggestion that you should never substitute a primary ingredient in a recipe.

Comment: +1 for the same reason. This is like asking what to substitute for the onion in onion soup.

Comment: I don't understand why whole wheat puff pastry would be lower in saturated fat--the actual goal of the question--than standard.  It is the fat in the recipe, not the flour, which is at issue.  Still, whole wheat will certainly be more fragile and difficult to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Croissant rolls or crescent rolls, found by the biscuits in the supermarket.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, that is puff pastry...

Comment: @Mien No, they are different.  You can buy frozen puff pastry dough, but it is a different item.

Answer (score -3):

This might be a wild bet, but I would try something out with tampura.

Comment: This would be extremely difficult to do, as tempura is a wet batter that is suitable for deep frying, while puff pastry is a rollable dough that is wrapped around the food item and baked.  Conversion of the recipe from one to the other would be essentially creating an entirely new recipe.